# What is the expected format of fontVariant in react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use `fontVariant` on a Text style. The [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text-style-props.html#fontvariant) says it expects an "array of enum". How does that look like in json? I have tried passing a string, and it <strike>works on android</strike> is ignored on android, but throws an error on ios:

```
<Text style={{ fontVariant: 'small-caps' }}>some text</Text>
```

will throw:

**JSON value 'small-caps' of type NSString cannot be converted to NSArray**

I am on version 0.53.3 react-native

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[According to the source PropTypes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/26684cf3adf4094eb6c405d345a75bf8c7c0bf88/Libraries/Text/TextStylePropTypes.js#L35), it expects an array of strings matching the enum:

```
<Text style={{ fontVariant: [ 'small-caps' ] }}>some text</Text>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that, but from native base theme files, and I got "styleName.indexOf is not a function". But that is a different story...

Comment: Test case showing usage here - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/26684cf3adf4094eb6c405d345a75bf8c7c0bf88/RNTester/js/TextExample.ios.js#L783  If you are using another framework alongside maybe that doesn't handle it properly.

Comment: It seems to have no effect in Android 10 and RN 0.64.

Comment: I concur with @Yogesch, but on Android 8 and RN 0.65.1.

Comment: Strange, because according to the example, it is supposed to have an effect on Android: https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.64/text-style-props#example